# Searching for a file or directory that will be created at boot on most/every Unix system

Tags: filesystems, boot

Sometimes it is useful to know about a specific file that the operating system will **create at boot**.
For example, you could use it in a **script** that needs to know the boot time.

Is there any "highly standard" file like this for all, or at least for many **Unix-like** operating systems, including embedded devices (routers, APs, webcams) or variants (BSD, CentOS, iOS)?

Comment: You can use the `uptime` command.

Comment: And on systems with a RTC, `who -b`. (Possibly not on embedded systems, though.)

Comment: You are right, @jordanm . Or the `who -b` command (not working on some BSD). Or the `sysctl kern.boottime` command (only on BSD). But none of these are file-based methods, and that is what the original question is about.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No, there is no such file.

A longer answer is:

No, there is no such file, and if there was the file's timestamp would be the time it was created which is not the same as the time the machine was booted.  Depending on where exactly in the boot process it was created, it might be seconds, minutes, or even longer after the system actually booted.

Some alternatives:

```
$ uptime
 10:06:50 up 31 days, 18:52, 21 users,  load average: 0.50, 0.54, 0.49

$ who -b
         system boot  2019-08-13 15:14

$ last reboot | head -n 1
reboot   system boot  5.2.0-2-amd64    Tue Aug 13 15:14   still running
```

None of these are guaranteed to have exactly the same output on different operating systems.  For example, the above commands were run on Debian GNU/Linux (sid). On my FreeBSD 12 VM, they look like this:

```
$ uptime
10:14AM  up 8 days, 23:12, 1 user, load averages: 0.25, 0.28, 0.26

$ who -b
                 system boot  Sep  5 11:02 

$ last reboot | head -n 1
boot time                                  Thu Sep  5 11:02
```

On linux, you can run a program called `uptimed` which records the boot and shutdown times.  You can query it with `uprecords`.  e.g.:

```
$ uprecords -B
     #               Uptime | System                                     Boot up
----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
->   1    31 days, 18:52:24 | Linux 5.2.0-2-amd64       Tue Aug 13 15:14:29 2019
     2    52 days, 20:45:19 | Linux 4.19.0-5-amd64      Fri Jun 21 18:21:54 2019
     3    51 days, 01:01:16 | Linux 4.19.0-4-amd64      Wed May  1 16:40:47 2019
     4     1 day , 01:13:47 | Linux 4.19.0-4-amd64      Tue Apr 30 14:54:34 2019
     5    21 days, 10:56:49 | Linux 4.19.0-4-amd64      Tue Apr  9 03:29:37 2019
     6     0 days, 01:20:59 | Linux 4.19.0-3-amd64      Tue Apr  9 02:01:15 2019
     7    41 days, 03:01:09 | Linux 4.19.0-3-amd64      Tue Feb 26 23:13:23 2019
     8     0 days, 01:40:57 | Linux 4.18.0-3-amd64      Tue Feb 26 21:29:41 2019
     9    20 days, 00:59:13 | Linux 4.18.0-3-amd64      Wed Feb  6 20:07:11 2019
    10    66 days, 00:02:21 | Linux 4.18.0-3-amd64      Sun Dec  2 19:05:03 2018
```

Comment: As long as many operating systems take minutes or even more to boot up, I think a delay of some minutes in the searched file is OK.